# how to break out of a loop when a page is reloading

Tags: c#, selenium

I have this code below where it goes through all of the links in a panel and once it is able find the relevant link, it will click it. The problem I have though is that when I select the link, the page reloads before it shows a new page. So I thought of adding a break to break out of the loop because if I don't add this, then it will give me a element is not attached to document error. I believe this error occurs because it is still trying to loop through the links whilst the page is reloading.

However, when adding the break and running the test, nothing happens as in it doesn't select a link. How can I break out of the loop after clicking the link?

I don't need to go back to the loop after the page has reloaded, I simply want to break out of the loop because the loop has done its job in finding the link and clicking.

```
    public void SelectHomepageSearchPanelLink(string linkText)
    {
        var searchPanelLinks = _driver.FindElements(HomepageResponsiveElements.HomepageSearchPanelLinks);

        foreach (var searchPanelLink in searchPanelLinks)
        {
            if (searchPanelLink.Text == linkText)
            {
               searchPanelLink.Click();
               break;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception($"{linkText} link not found by the responsive homepage search panel");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: don't you need to wait for that Click to be processed by the browser? I doubt page reload has anything to do with breaking or not breaking out of the loop. The code you show here looks fine.

Comment: Oh is that what it is, ah ok. Well, because this test is checking multiple pages,  I am not sure if each page has something that is the same to use a find element after the click. IS there a way I can simply check that the page is loading or finished loading?

Comment: OR better yet, is there a way I can wait for the click to be processed before breaking? So problem is if I remove the break then the click is processed but then I need to stop the loop or I get that document is not attached error

Comment: Normally a click would do something (show another div, load a page) so you would add waits: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void SelectHomepageSearchPanelLink(string linkText)
    {
        var searchPanelLinks = _driver.FindElements(HomepageResponsiveElements.HomepageSearchPanelLinks);
        var linkToClick;
        foreach (var searchPanelLink in searchPanelLinks)
        {
            if (searchPanelLink.Text == linkText)
            {
               linkToClick = searchPanelLink;
               break;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception($"{linkText} link not found by the responsive homepage search panel");
            }
        }
        linkToClick.Click();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't recognise the linkToClick.Click() afterwards for some strange reason

Comment: Variable is out of scope.Declare the variable out of the foreach loop.